# What signal can be connected to an initial dialog display in pyqt4 (qt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have an application in which I would like to connect whatever signal is emitted when a pyqt4 dialog is displayed in order to do execute an initial method. I don't want the method to be called in the `__init__` method for a number of reasons. I've spent quite some time searching but I have yet to find an answer. I'm sure there is a simple solution that because of my inexperience I am overlooking as I can do this in wxPython. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There is no signal emitted on first display, instead, you will have to intercept the first `resizeEvent` or `paintEvent` by overloading these methods (as you don't want to initialize from the `__init__` method).

Another option would be to add your own `showAndInit` method, that initializes and then calls `show`.

Comment: You could also intercept the showEvent method, which will be called when the dialog is scheduled to be shown (not quite right when it is shown).

Comment: Also, if you do not want to subclass, you can intercept all these events using an event filter, i.e. another class, which then can trigger the initialization.